# Looking for assistance passing environment variables to sshpass

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get a bash script to work, passing variables into sshpass, telnet and ssh. It's a horrible combination, but seemingly the only way I can toggle the status of my network switch POE status.

This is my script:

```
UNIFIUSER=xxx
UNIFIPASS=yyy
sshpass -p $UNIFIPASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $UNIFIUSER@10.10.10.53 '(echo "enable" ; echo "configure" ; echo "interface 0/8" ; echo  "poe opmode shutdown" ; echo "exit" ; echo "exit"; echo "exit"  ) | telnet localhost 23 ; exit;'
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
UNIFIUSER=xxx
UNIFIPASS=yyy

sshpass -p $UNIFIPASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $UNIFIUSER@10.10.10.53 '(echo "enable" ; echo "configure" ; echo "interface 0/8" ; echo  "**poe opmode $MODE**" ; echo "exit" ; echo "exit"; echo "exit"  ) | telnet localhost 23 ; exit;'
```

but I can't seem to get the $MODE parameter to work, it doesn't seem to make its way into the remote system.  I've also tried passing *env* but couldn't get that to work either.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Thanks

Jim

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid, I just couldn't see the obvious!

```bash
sshpass -p $UNIFIPASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $UNIFIUSER@10.10.10.53 '(echo "enable" ; echo "configure" ; echo "interface 0/8" ; echo  "poe opmode ' "$MODE" '" ; echo "exit" ; echo "exit"; echo "exit"  ) | telnet localhost 23 ; exit;'
```